# 7506 Error:The library for UDF/XSP/UDM HCPRE_AUTODDP.oreplace2 could not be found

Tags: teradata

Below are two queries. The first query runs fine. However the second one throws 7506 error. I recompiled the function however that didn't help.

```
SEL 
PID,
SimpleDefinitionID,
SimpleDefinitionName,
SimpleDefinitionQuery
,ABC.OREPLACE (cast(SimpleDefinitionQuery as varchar(1000)),') OR (',')')
FROM    ABC.SimpleDefinitions
where PID='71500001' 


SEL PID,
SimpleDefinitionID,
SimpleDefinitionName,
SimpleDefinitionQuery
,ABC.OREPLACE (cast(SimpleDefinitionQuery as varchar(1000)),') OR (',')')
FROM    ABC.SimpleDefinitions
where PID='71400001' ;
```

Any idea why that's happening?

Comment: Since TD14 there's a builtin `oReplace` located in `td_sysfnlib`, not need for your own one. How did you "recompile" this? Btw, both queries are the same.

Comment: We have created this in a user database modifying it a bit. I compiled it like below - ALTER SPECIFIC FUNCTION ABC.oreplace2 COMPILE; Yes both queries are same, just the PID is different. I believe the issue is the function is not created in all the nodes. Any idea how that can be accomplished?

Comment: The `COMPILE` option should distribute the `.so` file to all nodes, did you check the result for errors?

Comment: The compile only threw warnings...no errors -